# 20 кнопок для одной php программы

Tags: php, html

Как мне 20 кнопок присоединить к одной программе и так чтобы у каждой кнопки стояло aktion="card.php", но при нажатии разных кнопок производились соответствующие  действия в php программе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая вещь, как аргумент функции, их может быть несколько. Пример кода :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pg;
function fc (pg) {
 if (pg == 'home') {
  alert('home okok');
 }
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="fc('home')" value="домой" />
```

Аргументов может быть несколько.

По поводу связи с пхп, читаем [статью](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/).

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Вот так :

```
<a href="?param=ololo">link!1</a>
<?php
if ($_GET['param'] == 'ololo') {
 echo 'ololo now!1';
}
?>
```

Comment: Мне нужно php а не джава

Comment: Обязательно нужны кнопки? Или обойдёмся ссылками?

Comment: Хм. А как это сделать со ссылками?

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.